# Error "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Tags: php, sql

Quiero realizar un `insert`, utilicé varias tablas para hacer `INNER JOIN` y mostrarlo en tabla (CRUD), pero a la hora de insertar me arroja este error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`spa`.`ventas`, CONSTRAINT `ventas_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`id_manicurista`) REFERENCES `manicuristas` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)".

Desde phpMyAdmin realice los index y las relaciones.
Esto es parte del query:

###### Filtros para la tabla `ventas`

```sql
ALTER TABLE `ventas`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `ventas_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_servicio`) REFERENCES `servicios` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    ADD CONSTRAINT `ventas_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`precio`) REFERENCES `servicios` (`precio`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    ADD CONSTRAINT `ventas_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`id_manicurista`) REFERENCES `manicuristas` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

###### CODIGO PHP

```php
<?php 

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');

    $fecha = date('Y-m-d');

    $hora = date('H:i:s');

    NuevaVenta($_POST['manicurista'],
                $_POST['servicio'],
                    $_POST['precio'],
                        $fecha,
                            $hora);

    function NuevaVenta($manicurista, $servicio, $precio, $fecha, $hora){
        include 'db.php';
        $sentencia="INSERT INTO ventas (id_manicurista,id_servicio,precio,fecha,hora) VALUES('".$servicio."','".$manicurista."','".$precio."','".$fecha."','".$hora."') ";
        $conexion->query($sentencia) or die("ERROR AL REGISTRAR".mysqli_error($conexion));
    }
    
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema no tiene por qué estar en el código que aportas, sino en los datos que intentas registrar. El error te está diciendo que no puedes insertar un dato en el campo `id_manicurista` de la tabla `ventas` si previamente no existe en el campo `id` de la tabla `manicuristas`.

Comprueba si ese `id_manicurista` que pretendes registrar está en:

```
SELECT * FROM manicuristas
  WHERE id=el_id_manicurista_que_intentas_registrar;
```

Como no estará, regístralo con:

```
INSERT INTO manicuristas (id) VALUES
  (el_id_manicurista_que_intentas_registrar);
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Hola Agradezco tu tiempo, pero no estoy entendiendo. Manualmente desde PHPMYADMI me realiza el registro e incluso el campo manicurista lo traigo desde un <select> con PHP realizando la consulta en la BD y uso un While para imprimirlo en el select

Comment: Muestra el contenido de las tablas y el SQL que genera tu aplicación para comprobar si el `INSERT` funciona en la base de datos